# Oracle Sql left join return null value on condition.

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Hi I have a left join like

```
Select * from tables a 
Left join tableB b on b.id = a.id and b.name ='avc';
```

This query also return record were b.name is null.. 
Could someone plz explain the reason.

Comment: That's the LEFT JOIN way (if b.id also is null.)

Comment: If you want no results when joining on data that does not exist, you should use `INNER JOIN`. What you are currently describing is just the way a `LEFT JOIN` works. This is often used if it's unwanted that results from the main table dissappear because there's no link in the child tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an INNER JOIN to avoid nulls.

```
SELECT * FROM tables a 
INNER JOIN tableB b 
ON b.id = a.id and b.name ='avc';
```

Check [this](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-_HsHikmChBI/VmQGJjLKgyI/AAAAAAAAEPw/JaLnV0bsbEo/s1600/sql%2Bjoins%2Bguide%2Band%2Bsyntax.jpg)  for more information about joins.